# Topic Challenges III: Return of the Topic

Tags: discussion, topic-challenges

Well, it's been a while.

To our new(-er) users, welcome to Topic Challenges. To our old(-er) users, welcome back.

In the spirit of improving the site, its questions and the amount of fun and learning (and teaching) that goes here, a tradition lost to time is now rekindled.

I'm talking, of course, about [Topic Challenges](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207/topic-challenges).

The idea is to have a competition of sorts. Rather than have users compete, their questions compete. A better and more thorough description is in the [linked post](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207/topic-challenges).

The abridged version is:

1. A topic is chosen by the community, in Q&A style, right in this post. You can suggest a topic theme (see challenges [#1](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210/topic-challenge-01-the-review-spew) and [#2](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275/topic-challenge-02-being-selfish) if you want a better idea of what's what) by posting your suggestion as an answer to this very question
2. Once a Topic is chosen, a meta post (like the [previous](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210/topic-challenge-01-the-review-spew) [two](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275/topic-challenge-02-being-selfish)) will go up, and the challenge will begin [**24 hours later**](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/a/208/150) (specific time will be stated in the post)
3. The challenges last one (1) week*. At the end of the week, a winner is announced by our <s>all powerful</s> amazing mod team.
4. You can find more details in [here](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207/topic-challenges).

And remember: There's no such thing as a wrong answer here! It's not CS *Education* if you're not allowed to make mistakes. So suggest to your hearts <s>contest</s> content!

Whichever topic is chosen, remember: It's best to add the comment:

`*This question has been entered into [#### challenge question contest](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/...).*` to your question, once a challenge is announced and the 24 hour period passes.

---

* Usually

Answer (score 3):

I'll not sure if there's enough support for a topic challenge, but if we did one, perhaps it should be simply for the number of well-received questions within the contest period?

Comment: but still include the `*This question has been entered into [#### challenge question contest](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/...).*` comment... because we **have** to raise awareness.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion:
Properly visible.

quite simple. Any [c](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c),[c++](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b),[c#](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tagged question (should the asker choose to participate).